# How to remove arrow in searchview collapse?

Tags: android, searchview

i just put searchView on toolbar but i getting on issue when i collapse searchView i getting on arrow i mention in this photo..searchview is in menu folder ..so give some suggestion to how to remove this arrow......thanks in advance [image: searchview screenshot image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context="com.play.findnearplace.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/search"
         app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"

          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
          {
             filter.filter("");
            }
          else
          {
              filter.filter(newText.toString());
            }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any inflation code? where are you inflating it in your main activity? Can you post that?

Comment: here is my inflation code which i declare and handle searchview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line to get rid of that arrow:

```
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```

See documentation for searchView [submit button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setSubmitButtonEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Thanks naveed ...its remove